# How to make a loop start and stop with gesture notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am attempting to dynamically scroll a UICollectionView when a user long presses and drags a cell to either side of the visible cells. Unfortunately, longPress only receives notifications for stateChanged, but if their finger is in the right place, I want it to continue scrolling (even if it's not moving). What would be the best way to start a loop to scroll the view then stop it when the user has moved their finger away from the edge?

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this yourself yet? How are you dragging the cell?

Comment: Of course I've tried. Why would I post if I thought I could find a solution on my own? I drag the cell by inflating a rasterized image of it when user long presses, then update the location of the image based on where the user's finger is.

Comment: If you have tried it, then please tell us about how you've tried it. Also, that is a very bad way of showing cell dragging. Anyways, how do you actually track your touches? Please post any information about your implementation which you think is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a CADisplayLink to start and stop my loop. I start it when the gesture begin's and I use it's selector method to determine whether or not the view should be scrolled. I then invalidate it when the gesture has ended.

My inspiration came from here: https://github.com/shusta/ReorderingTableViewController/blob/master/ATSDragToReorderTableViewController.m

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it (and this may be improper) would be to listen to touch events as well as the long-press gesture.  (The long press may cancel all of your touch events, so you may have to do long press manually)

When you get a long press on an object you set a variable in your class instance something like `iAmLongPressing`.  Then you start listening to your `touchesMoved` method.  Once you get close enough to the edge of the screen you start a timer that fires off every however long you want to scroll pages.  If your user's finger is still on the screen and near the edge at the next timer tick (or 10 timer ticks, or whatever) you scroll to the next page.  When you get a `touchesEnded` call you set the `iAmLongPressing` to false and when your timer notices that you are no longer long pressing you cancel it (or you can cancel the timer in the `touchesEnded` call to be safe).  I don't have a code example for you since you didn't mention how you are currently working, but it should be pretty straight forward.  Just modify the timer interval and the "side of page" spacing until it feels right to you.